# PHP - $row[$variable] in function

Tags: php, mysql, function, variables

I'm trying to call $row (database array) from within a function but calling the column name based on a variable.

Here is the full code... You can see the results at

http://tlcs.stuart-pinfold.co.uk/test.php?id=20

and

http://tlcs.stuart-pinfold.co.uk/test.php?id=21

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php"); // includes all the db connections

$id = $_GET['id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID='".$id."'";
$set = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($set);

function checkAvailability($day)
{
 $check = "UserCommute".$day;
 if($row[$check]=="1")
 {
  echo '<img src="/tick.jpg" alt="Available on this day" />';
 }
 else
 {
  echo '<img src="/cross.jpg" alt="Not available on this day" />';
 }
 echo " = ".$check."<br/>";
}

echo "Full Name:<br/>".$row['UserFullName']; // this works perfectly

echo "<br/><br/>Using the function...<br/>";

echo checkAvailability('Mon');
echo checkAvailability('Tue');
echo checkAvailability('Wed');
echo checkAvailability('Thu');
echo checkAvailability('Fri');
echo checkAvailability('Sat');
echo checkAvailability('Sun'); // these always return a cross even when the database entry is 1

echo "<br/>Using hard-coded row values...<br/>";

echo $row['UserCommuteMon']." = UserCommuteMon<br/>";
echo $row['UserCommuteTue']." = UserCommuteTue<br/>";
echo $row['UserCommuteWed']." = UserCommuteWed<br/>";
echo $row['UserCommuteThu']." = UserCommuteThu<br/>";
echo $row['UserCommuteFri']." = UserCommuteFri<br/>";
echo $row['UserCommuteSat']." = UserCommuteSat<br/>";
echo $row['UserCommuteSun']." = UserCommuteSun<br/>"; // these work perfectly, returning 0s or 1s, matching the database

?>
```

It only returns crosses, never ticks.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: can you var_dump $row[$check] inside your function to see what it is returning?

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to [SQL injections](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)!

Comment: ... and uses the deprecated mysql_* extensions. Switch to one of the newer APIs: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: del-ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900254/php-rowvariable-in-function

Comment: @Ay34 - didn't make any difference.

Comment: @Gumbo - Not on the real code, this was a broken-down version of it.

Comment: @ZombieHunter - Thanks, didn't realise that, will look into the newer APIs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining a function, inside the function there is no scope of `$row`.

Either define a new query there that will check if the user is available on a given day or remove the function and compare the field without the function.

So instead of doing `checkAvailability('Mon');` do:

```
if($row["UserCommuteMon"] === 1) {

}
```

or give `$row` to your function. Like `checkAvailability($row, 'Mon');`

And remember to clean your `$_GET['id']` to prevent SQL-injections.

Comment: Exactly! $row does not exist inside your checkAvailability() function

Comment: @Tim - Giving $row to the function didn't make any difference. And the real code is safe from SQL injections - this was just a stripped-down version of it.

Comment: You have to change your function to function checkAvailability($row, $day). I think it's nicer to not use the function but do it directly in the code as you edited.

Answer (score 1):

You have mutliple problems in your code and it can greatly be improved.

Consider switching to anonymous functions:

```
$checkAvailabilityDay = function($day) use ($row)
{
    $key   = "UserCommute$day";
    $check = $row[$key] == 1;
    echo '<img src="/', $check ? 'tick' : 'cross', '.jpg" alt="',
         $check ? 'Available' : 'Not available', ' on this day" />',
         "$key<br />\n";
}
```

They allow to use (import) variables from the scope they are defined in. It is used here for the `$row` variable. The functions can be used like any other function, for example as a callback for the output of all days:

```
array_map($checkAvailabilityDay, ['Mon', Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']);
```

I hope this is helpful. You should also drop `mysql_*` for many reasons, consider to switch to PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all. I've ended up with the (in my opinion) much more inefficient:

```
<?php

if($row['UserCommuteMon']===1)
{
 echo '<img src="/tick.jpg" alt="Travels on this day" class="availIcon" />';
}
else
{
 echo '<img src="/cross.jpg" alt="Does not travel on this day" class="availIcon" />';
}
echo "Mon";

if($row['UserCommuteTue']===1)
{
 echo '<img src="/tick.jpg" alt="Travels on this day" class="availIcon" />';
}
else
{
 echo '<img src="/cross.jpg" alt="Does not travel on this day" class="availIcon" />';
}
echo "Tue";

if($row['UserCommuteWed']===1)
{
 echo '<img src="/tick.jpg" alt="Travels on this day" class="availIcon" />';
}
else
{
 echo '<img src="/cross.jpg" alt="Does not travel on this day" class="availIcon" />';
}
echo "Wed";

etc...

?>
```